# Istio not routing traffic to specific pod

Tags: istio

I have setup a bunch of containers on k8s. Each pod runs one container. There is a reverse proxy pod that calls a service in a runtime container. I have set up two runtime pods v1 and v2. My goal is to use istio to route all traffic from the reverse proxy pod to the runtime pod v1.

I have configured istio and the screen shots below will give you an idea about the environment.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My k8s yaml looks like this:

```
#Assumes create-docker-store-secret.sh used to create dockerlogin secret
#Assumes create-secrets.sh used to create key file, sam admin, and cfgsvc secrets
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
# Create StorageClass with gidallocate=true to allow non-root user access to mount
# This is used by PostgreSQL container
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
   name: ibmc-file-bronze-gid
   labels:
     kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
provisioner: ibm.io/ibmc-file
parameters:
   type: "Endurance"
   iopsPerGB: "2"
   sizeRange: "[1-12000]Gi"
   mountOptions: nfsvers=4.1,hard
   billingType: "hourly"
   reclaimPolicy: "Delete"
   classVersion: "2"
   gidAllocate: "true"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ldaplib
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ldapslapd
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ldapsecauthority
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgresqldata
spec:
  storageClassName: ibmc-file-bronze-gid
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: isamconfig
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50M
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: openldap
  labels:
    app: openldap
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: openldap
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: openldap
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: ldaplib
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ldaplib
        - name: ldapslapd
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ldapslapd
        - name: ldapsecauthority
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ldapsecauthority
        - name: openldap-keys
          secret:
            secretName: openldap-keys
      containers:
        - name: openldap
          image: ibmcom/isam-openldap:9.0.7.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 636
          env:
            - name: LDAP_DOMAIN
              value: ibm.com
            - name: LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: Passw0rd
            - name: LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD
              value: Passw0rd
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/ldap
              name: ldaplib
            - mountPath: /etc/ldap/slapd.d
              name: ldapslapd
            - mountPath: /var/lib/ldap.secAuthority
              name: ldapsecauthority
            - mountPath: /container/service/slapd/assets/certs
              name: openldap-keys
# This line is needed when running on Kubernetes 1.9.4 or above
          args: [ "--copy-service"]

# useful for debugging startup issues - can run bash, then exec to the container and poke around
#          command: [ "/bin/bash"]
#          args: [ "-c", "while /bin/true ; do sleep 5; done" ]
# Just this line to get debug output from openldap startup
#          args: [ "--loglevel" , "trace","--copy-service"]
---
# for external service access, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: openldap
  labels:
    app: openldap
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 636
      name: ldaps
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: openldap
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgresql
  labels:
    app: postgresql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 70
        fsGroup: 0
      volumes:
        - name: postgresqldata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgresqldata
        - name: postgresql-keys
          secret:
            secretName: postgresql-keys
      containers:
        - name: postgresql
          image: ibmcom/isam-postgresql:9.0.7.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: Passw0rd
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: isam
            - name: POSTGRES_SSL_KEYDB
              value: /var/local/server.pem
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/db-files/
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresqldata
            - mountPath: /var/local
              name: postgresql-keys
# useful for debugging startup issues - can run bash, then exec to the container and poke around
#          command: [ "/bin/bash"]
#          args: [ "-c", "while /bin/true ; do sleep 5; done" ]
---
# for external service access, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      name: postgresql
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: postgresql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: isamconfig
  labels:
    app: isamconfig
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: isamconfig
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: isamconfig
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser:    6000
      volumes:
        - name: isamconfig
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: isamconfig
        - name: isamconfig-logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: isamconfig
          image: ibmcom/isam:9.0.7.1_IF4
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/shared
              name: isamconfig
            - mountPath: /var/application.logs
              name: isamconfig-logs
          env:
            - name: SERVICE
              value: config
            - name: CONTAINER_TIMEZONE
              value: Europe/London
            - name: ADMIN_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: samadmin
                  key: adminpw
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port:  9443
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 9443
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 20
#          command: [ "/sbin/bootstrap.sh" ]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerlogin
---
# for external service access, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamconfig
spec:
# To make the LMI internet facing, make it a NodePort
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9443
      name: isamconfig
      protocol: TCP
# make this one statically allocated
      nodePort: 30442
  selector:
    app: isamconfig
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: isamwrprp1
  labels:
    app: isamwrprp1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: isamwrprp1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: isamwrprp1
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser:    6000
      volumes:
        - name: isamconfig
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: isamwrprp1-logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: isamwrprp1
          image: ibmcom/isam:9.0.7.1_IF4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/shared
              name: isamconfig
            - mountPath: /var/application.logs
              name: isamwrprp1-logs
          env:
            - name: SERVICE
              value: webseal
            - name: INSTANCE
              value: rp1
            - name: CONTAINER_TIMEZONE
              value: Europe/London
            - name: AUTO_RELOAD_FREQUENCY
              value: "5"
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_URL
              value: https://isamconfig:9443/shared_volume
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_NAME
              value: cfgsvc
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: configreader
                  key: cfgsvcpw
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
              - livenessProbe
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerlogin
---
# for external service access, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamwrprp1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: isamwrprp1
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30443
  selector:
    app: isamwrprp1
---
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: isamwrpmobile
  labels:
    app: isamwrpmobile
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: isamwrpmobile
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: isamwrpmobile
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser:    6000
      volumes:
        - name: isamconfig
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: isamwrpmobile-logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: isamwrpmobile
          image: ibmcom/isam:9.0.7.1_IF4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/shared
              name: isamconfig
            - mountPath: /var/application.logs
              name: isamwrpmobile-logs
          env:
            - name: SERVICE
              value: webseal
            - name: INSTANCE
              value: mobile
            - name: CONTAINER_TIMEZONE
              value: Europe/London
            - name: AUTO_RELOAD_FREQUENCY
              value: "5"
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_URL
              value: https://isamconfig:9443/shared_volume
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_NAME
              value: cfgsvc
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: configreader
                  key: cfgsvcpw
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
              - livenessProbe
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerlogin
---
# for external service access, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamwrpmobile
spec:
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: isamwrpmobile
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30444
  selector:
    app: isamwrpmobile
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-v1
  labels:
    app: isamruntime
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: isamruntime
      version: v1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: isamruntime
        version: v1
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser:    6000
      volumes:
        - name: isamconfig
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: isamruntime-logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: isamruntime
          image: ibmcom/isam:9.0.7.1_IF4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/shared
              name: isamconfig
            - mountPath: /var/application.logs
              name: isamruntime-logs
          env:
            - name: SERVICE
              value: runtime
            - name: CONTAINER_TIMEZONE
              value: Europe/London
            - name: AUTO_RELOAD_FREQUENCY
              value: "5"
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_URL
              value: https://isamconfig:9443/shared_volume
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_NAME
              value: cfgsvc
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: configreader
                  key: cfgsvcpw
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
              - livenessProbe
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerlogin
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-v2
  labels:
    app: isamruntime
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: isamruntime
      version: v2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: isamruntime
        version: v2
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser:    6000
      volumes:
        - name: isamconfig
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: isamruntime-logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: isamruntime
          image: ibmcom/isam:9.0.7.1_IF4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/shared
              name: isamconfig
            - mountPath: /var/application.logs
              name: isamruntime-logs
          env:
            - name: SERVICE
              value: runtime
            - name: CONTAINER_TIMEZONE
              value: Europe/London
            - name: AUTO_RELOAD_FREQUENCY
              value: "5"
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_URL
              value: https://isamconfig:9443/shared_volume
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_NAME
              value: cfgsvc
            - name: CONFIG_SERVICE_USER_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: configreader
                  key: cfgsvcpw
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
              - livenessProbe
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /sbin/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerlogin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: isamruntime
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: isamruntime
---
```

I have my gateway yaml file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /tmp/tls.crt
      privateKey: /tmp/tls.key
---
```

and my routing yaml file looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  hosts:
    - isamruntime
  gateways:
    - isamruntime-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v1
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  host: isamruntime
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

The flow goes from Postman tool -> ingress ip address -> container that runs the reverse proxy -> Runtime container
My goal is to ensure only the container on the runtime v1 pod gets the traffic. However, the traffic gets routed to both v1 and v2.

What is my mistake ? Can someone help me ?

Regards
Pranam

I tried the following but it didnt work. The traffic gets routed to v1 and v2.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  hosts:
    - isamruntime
  gateways:
    - isamruntime-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v1
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v2
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 0
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-v1
spec:
  host: isamruntime
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
---
```

I tried changing my virtualservice to look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  hosts:
    - isamruntime.com
  gateways:
    - isamruntime-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v1
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v2
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 0
---
```

I then used curl as shown below

```
pranam@UNKNOWN kubernetes % curl -k -v -H "host: isamruntime.com" https://169.50.228.2:30443
*   Trying 169.50.228.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 169.50.228.2 (169.50.228.2) port 30443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; O=Policy Director; CN=isamconfig
*  start date: Feb 18 15:33:30 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 14 15:33:30 2038 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Policy Director; CN=isamconfig
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: isamruntime.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 13104
< content-type: text/html
< date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 13:45:28 GMT
< p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
< server: WebSEAL/9.0.7.1
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< cache-control: no-store
< x-xss-protection: 1
< content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: PD-S-SESSION-ID=1_2_0_cGgEZiwrYKP0QtvDtZDa4l7-iPb6M3ZsW4I+aeUhn9HuAfAd; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2015 IBM Corporation -->
<!-- Copyright (C) 2000 Tivoli Systems, Inc. -->
<!-- Copyright (C) 1999 IBM Corporation -->
<!-- Copyright (C) 1998 Dascom, Inc. -->
<!-- All Rights Reserved. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LoginPage</title>
    <style>
```

The curl command returns the login page of a reverse proxy which is expected. My runtime service is behind the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy will call the runtime service. I saw somewhere in the documentation that -mesh can be used. That didn't help my cause either.

I ran another curl command that actually triggers a call to the reverse proxy and the reverse proxy calls the runtime.

```
curl -k -v -H "host: isamruntime.com" https://169.50.228.2:30443/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token
*   Trying 169.50.228.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 169.50.228.2 (169.50.228.2) port 30443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; O=Policy Director; CN=isamconfig
*  start date: Feb 18 15:33:30 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 14 15:33:30 2038 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Policy Director; CN=isamconfig
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: isamruntime.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-language: en-US
< content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 13:56:32 GMT
< p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache=set-cookie
< expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: AMWEBJCT!%2Fmga!JSESSIONID=00004EKuX3PlcIBBhcwGnKf50ac:9e48435e-a71f-4b8a-8fb6-ef95c5f36c51; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: PD_STATEFUL_c728ed2e-159a-11e8-b9c9-0242ac120004=%2Fmga; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: PD-S-SESSION-ID=1_2_0_6kSM-YBjsgCZnwNGOCOvjA+C9KBhYXlKkyuWUKpZ7RnCKVcy; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< 
* Connection #0 to host 169.50.228.2 left intact
{"error_description":"FBTOAU232E The client MUST use the HTTP POST method when making access token requests.","error":"invalid_request"}* Closing connection 0
```

Error is expected as that is an end point that allows only HTTP POST.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOMnD.png

Comment: Hello @Pranam Codur, did below christoph advice solved your issue? If that didn´t work could you try to add second destination for subset v2 and put here `weight:0`?

Comment: @jt97 Thanks for looking at my question. The answer below captures some changes I tried. But it did not work.

Comment: Please instead of creating the answer just edit your question with new informations with edit button, instead of creating 2 destination rules use your original one and use virtual service from your below answer. about hostname, as far as I can see it´s in default namespace, so `isamruntime` should work, just to be sure you can try change it to `isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: @jt97 Sorry. I have edited the question. I tried both isamruntime and isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local. However, it does not work. Is there a chance it is because my isamruntime is in default namespace and istio is in a different namespace ?

Comment: Istio should be in a istio-system namespace, your pods,services gateways,virtual services, destiantion rules might be in default namespace, but it must be labeled, as far as I can see you did it, so it should work. Could you try to change virtual service hosts from `hosts:
    - isamruntime` to `hosts:
    - isamruntime.com` and use `curl -v -H "host: isamruntime.com" istio-ingressgateway-ip/`, could you curl it few times and show the results?

Comment: @jt97  I am exposing a reverse proxy via node port. I ran a curl command to hit the reverse proxy and passed the header as you mentioned. It shows a login page as expected. The details are above ( in the original question ).  Actually at this point no traffic is passed to the runtime as I am hitting only a reverse proxy. I ran another command  ( again details above ) that actually hits the runtime via the reverse proxy.  Does it give any useful info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the flow working. I did not need a gateway as my traffic is going from the reverse proxy -> runtime. The reverse proxy and runtime are inside the k8s cluser and is east-west traffic. My service needed a tcp- and my virtual service needed tcp mapping. The yaml files are given below. I thank all of you to guide me in the right direction.
my service yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: tcp-isamruntime # Add prefix of tcp to match traffic type
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: isamruntime
```

my virtual service and destination rule yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  hosts:
    - isamruntime
  tcp:
    - match:
      - port: 443
      route:
      - destination:
          host: isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 443
          subset: v1
        weight: 0
      - destination:
          host: isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 443
          subset: v2
        weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  host: isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
---
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

> the traffic gets routed to both v1 and v2

This most likely means Istio is not handling the traffic, and K8s Service is doing simple round-robin.

I think you are seeing the exact situation covered in [Debugging Istio: How to Fix a Broken Service Mesh (Cloud Next '19)](https://youtu.be/FbYBO7Pi2d8) session.

It's a really useful session for seeing the power of `istioctl` and debugging unexpected behaviours, but long story short for your case, you would need to adjust Service definition.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: http-isamruntime # Add prefix of http
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: isamruntime
```

Ref: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService

NOTE: The above `http-` prefix assumes you are terminating TLS before hitting the Service. Depending on your use case, you may need to adjust VirtualService as well.

Comment: thanks for the link. The service definition should have a prefix of "http". Then, when I create a virtual service, does that need the same name ? i.e http-isamruntime

Comment: In my environment the flow the client ( REST client ) will call a service. The service goes to a reverse proxy. The TLS is terminated at the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy makes a call to the runtime serivice. This is a new TLS connection and internal to what I guess is called the ''mesh''. So, I am guessing your suggestion that http prefix is needed is correct. However, when I use the http-prefix the service call fails. example : if service is http-isamruntime my use case flow breaks.

Comment: The K8s Service name is what you define in the `metadata.name` - in the above case, it's `isamruntime`. You don't need a prefix for this. The `http` prefix is for the port in the Service, and VirtualService reads this port name to figure out the protocol. After looking into this a bit more closely, I found Istio v1.5 onwards now supports [automatic protocol selection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/#automatic-protocol-selection), so you may not need this if you have the protocol information associated elsewhere.

Comment: I am on istio 1.5.6. I tried using a tls prefix. That doesnt work either.

Comment: for traffic that is being routed inside the mesh do I need a gateway ?

Comment: As to the prefix, what kind of error are you seeing? You may want to run `istioctl analyze -A`, which validates the current mesh configuration in play.
As to the gateway, you shouldn't need a separate gateway definition, unless you want to have finer control over the traffic (e.g. restrict VirtualService namespace, additional port mapping, custom TLS initiation, etc.). You can check out the details in [the official examples and spec](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/).

Answer (score 0):

jt97

Thanks for looking at the question. I tried yours suggestions using this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: isamruntime
spec:
  hosts:
    - isamruntime
  gateways:
    - isamruntime-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v1
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: isamruntime
        subset: v2
        port:
           number: 443
      weight: 0
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-v1
spec:
  host: isamruntime
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
#  - name: v2
#    labels:
#      version: v2
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: isamruntime-v2
spec:
  host: isamruntime
  subsets:
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
#  - name: v2
#    labels:
#      version: v2
```

But, it did not work.

Has it got to do with hostname. Does it have to have the namespace like - isamruntime.default.svc.cluster.local  or should my containers be running in a non-default namespace ?

Regards
Pranam